# Socket exception requested address is not valid in its context 74.125.200.27:25 in C#

Tags: c#

```
TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
string CRLF = "\r\n";
byte[] dataBuffer;
string ResponseString;
NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();


///* Perform HELO to SMTP Server and get Response */
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO Congnition Infosystem Here" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("MAIL FROM:<pachirit99@gmail.com>" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
```

While executing the TcpClient ## Heading ##line by compiler it showing like `the requested address is not valid in its context 74.125.200.27:25` ....how to solve this?

Comment: When executing _what_? I don't see anything in your code example that looks like `the TcpClient ## Heading ##line by compiler`. The exception you're getting is what would happen if you tried to bind a socket to an address other than one hosted by the local machine. But nothing in the code you posted would try to bind to any specific IP address. You'll need to provide better details, including [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, the very first line in the code sample above.  What is the `SocketException.ErrorCode`?  See the remarks section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx